# Azure SQL data warehouse - do transaction limits apply to CTAS opperations?

Tags: azure-sql-data-warehouse

Azure SQL Data Warehouse has limits on the maximum size of a transaction (as [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-transactions)). As CTAS operations cannot be performed inside a transaction, I was wondering if these limits still applied?

Comment: If you can keep your `CTAS` operation as minimally logged then it is not bounded with that restriction. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-best-practices-transactions).

Comment: @SqlWorldWide that was exactly what  I was looking for! would you like to make it an answer for internet points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-best-practices-transactions

The transaction safety limits only apply to fully logged operations. `CTAS` is capable of being minimally logged.  So answer depends, if `CTAS` is minimally logged safety limit does not apply and vice versa.

> Unlike fully logged operations, which use the transaction log to keep
>   track of every row change, minimally logged operations keep track of
>   extent allocations and meta-data changes only. Therefore, minimal
>   logging involves logging only the information that is required to
>   rollback the transaction in the event of a failure or an explicit
>   request (ROLLBACK TRAN). As much less information is tracked in the
>   transaction log, a minimally logged operation performs better than a
>   similarly sized fully logged operation. Furthermore, because fewer
>   writes go the transaction log, a much smaller amount of log data is
>   generated and so is more I/O efficient.